# TSQL DatePart Week in ww format 01 instead of 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, week-number, datepart

What is the best way to get the week from a date in the format 01 02 03 04 05 rather than 1 2 3 4 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest method is to concatenate your leading `0`s and then taking the two rightmost values:

```
select right(concat('00', DATEPART(week, getdate())), 2) as WeekNum
```

You do not need a udf for this...

Answer (score 1):

Please check [SQL left padding function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-pad-leading-zeros.aspx) how you can implement as follows

```
DECLARE @Dt datetime
SELECT @Dt='01-21-2008'
SELECT dbo.udfLeftSQLPadding( CAST( DATEPART(wk, @Dt) AS NVARCHAR),2,'0')
```

Function uses Replicate() with other functions like Right(), etc as below

```
SELECT RIGHT(Replicate('0', 2) + CAST( DATEPART(wk, @Dt) AS NVARCHAR), 2)
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: Is that what you want??

Comment: <Comment Removed>

Answer (score 0):

The basic way with [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx), [RIGHT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx) and [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

```
DECLARE @d date = '2016-01-01'

SELECT RIGHT(STUFF(DATEPART(week,@d),1,0,'0'),2)
```

Output:

```
01
```

`STUFF` adds `0` in front of week number, then `RIGHT` cuts 2 characters from a right side.

Answer (score 0):

You can also concat strings

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(week,@d) < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END +  DATEPART(week,@d)
```

Answer (score 0):

A faster and better performing alternative to dbo.udfLeftSQLPadding would be an inline table valued function with the same logic. It would look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.iTVFLeftSQLPadding 
(
  @String      varchar(100),
  @Length      smallint,
  @PaddingChar char(1) = '0'
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN 
SELECT newstring = RIGHT(REPLICATE(@PaddingChar, @Length) + @String, @Length);
```

You can learn more about this technique here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/91724/